# How can i retrieve how many time a field with datatype (Lookup / Long Text Area ) being changed using SOQL on Case History?

Tags: soql, history-tracking, field-history

Using this Soql :   `SELECT count(case.subject) FROM CaseHistory where field ='subject'`  i was able to retrieve number of time *Subject field* has changed

Since we can not filter by *OldValue / NewValue* , Is there a way  to retrieve number of time **lookup/LongText/RecordType** field has changed using soql?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the number of times a long text field has changed, first ensure that `Your_Long_Text_Field__c` is history-tracked in Setup menu, or was at some point, and has seen data changes. Then run this:

`SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Your_Long_Text_Field__c'`

You can do something similar for `RecordTypeId`, or `Your_Custom_Lookup__c`

**Note about counting changes to lookup fields:**

You can avoid double counting `lookup` field changes by further filtering the query by DataType. For example, ContactId is a lookup field, found by field='contact' on the CaseHistory sobject, and we apply `DataType` filters to avoid double-counting as it seems when a lookup field value changes,  the history table tracks the text/label change separately from its referenceable id :
`SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Contact' AND DataType='Text'`
vs
`SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Contact' AND DataType='EntityId'`

Comment: It doesn't work with **Lookup** field or **RecordType** , `SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'ContactId'` . ContactId is history-tacked but the soql is returning  0 row

Comment: Hmm, for whatever reason, the conventions different: you have to filter like this `SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Contact'`   notice for some reason field='contactid' wont work

Comment: Thanks but it return wrong result - Example : if i change contact name on case  **1 time** the soql return **2** , if i change the contact name **2 times** it return **4** - it count the old and new value

Comment: Same, i suspect thats a design of lookup fields because when in testing, i see when a lookup field changes the history table increases twice.  Once for DataType=Text, once for DataType=EntityId.  In other words try one of these when counting lookup field changes (either):
`SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Contact' AND DataType='Text'` or `SELECT Count(Id) from CaseHistory where field = 'Contact' AND DataType='EntityId'`

Comment: Or just devide the number by 2 lol , sorry but what do you mean by **DataType = 'Text'** ,  **EntityId**? it's a lookup ..

Comment: Based on my tests, `DataType` is a column/field on the `CaseHistory` sobject.  Regarding lookup-field-behavior it seems that when a lookup value changes, the result is two entries in  *History object;   one for the lookups text/label which can be filtered/found by applying the `DataType = 'Text'` filter to the query, and one for its referenceable id which can be filtered/found by applying `DataType='EntityId'` to the soql query.

Comment: yes i got it but why you used Text/EntityId as DataType?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118176/discussion-between-peter-noges-and-farkous).